# Isomorphism of rigged Hilbert spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

In connection with the statement that QM can be formulated in terms of separable complex (rigged) Hilbert spaces, the fact that all infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert spaces are isomorphic to one another is sometimes emphasized.

I understand why some authors like to add "(rigged)" in order hint how to make this slightly simplified statement more rigorous, but is this modification also compatible the "additional hint" that all "physically relevant" Hilbert spaces are isomorphic? For a "physically relevant" [rigged Hilbert space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space), the ket space has to be nuclear:

> A **[nuclear space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_space)** is a topological vector space with a topology defined by a family of Hilbert seminorms, such that for any Hilbert seminorm $p$ we can find a larger Hilbert seminorm $q$ so that the natural map from $V_q$ to $V_p$ is [trace class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class).

So I have some questions:

1. I have the impression that rigged Hilbert spaces don't add anything for finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, especially all finite dimensional rigged Hilbert spaces of the same dimension should be isomorphic. Is this correct?
2. Are there simple examples of non-isomorphic infinite dimensional separable rigged Hilbert spaces where the ket space is nuclear?
3. Are the most common examples of the $\mathbb R$- and $\mathbb R^3$-[Schwartz-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) (i.e. $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathscr{S'}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^3) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) \subset \mathscr{S'}(\mathbb{R}^3)$) examples of non-isomorphic rigged Hilbert spaces?
4. Is the $\mathbb R^3$-Schwartz-space at least isomorphic to a subspace of the $\mathbb R$-Schwartz-space?

Comment: Keep in mind that neither the Schwarz space $\mathscr{S}$ nor its dual $\mathscr{S}'$ are Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @yuggib What I mean is the rigged Hilbert space given by $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathscr{S'}(\mathbb{R})$. I edited the question to clarify this. I also added a link to "rigged Hilbert space" for readers who are unfamiliar with the definition of *rigged Hilbert space* in terms of a sandwich $S\subset H \subset S'$.

Comment: 1. The RHS is relevant for continuous spectrum only, so it is relevant for infinite dimensions only;
2. I'd need to investigate on this;
3. My feeling is that they are isomorphic: the $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ spaces surely are, as they are all separable; moreover $\mathscr S(\mathbb R^n)$ must be infinite-dimensional and at most separable, so that it should be possible to construct isomorphisms between them (but I haven't checked this!)
4. Related to the previous point.

Comment: I know what the rigging means...but I don't clearly understand your question. The isomorphism of Hilbert spaces is due, in simple terms, to the fact that for each separable Hilbert space it is possible to choose a countable orthonormal basis. This does not give, however any information on the topology you choose on dense sets.

Comment: What is your definition of a "morphism of rigged Hilbert spaces", in particular, of an isomorphism between them?

Comment: @ACuriousMind A morphism from $S\subset H\subset S'$ to $T\subset K \subset T'$ should at least provide a continuous linear transformation from $S$ to $T$. By transposition, this automatically also gives a continuous linear transformation from $T'$ to $S'$. It would be great if the transformation would also preserve the scalar product, but if not then I won't mind too much either.

Comment: i think that a good definition of isomorphism should definitely preserve the inner product

Comment: @Phoenix87 I know from John Baez that defining appropriate morphisms to give the desired structure to the resulting category is a tricky question: [The *-Category of Hilbert Spaces](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/quantum/node3.html)! The morphisms are not required to preserve the inner product, but the inner product can be completely recovered from the *-category structure. Because this is so subtle, I tried to go with a simple clear and workable definition instead, which should be sufficient for answering this question.

Comment: @Phoenix87 You are right, the Schwartz spaces are indeed isomorphic. Yurii Savchuk provided a [proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150549) that the obvious candidate mapping is an isomorphism. I added a community wiki answer with a link and a short summary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specify a Gel'fand triple $(\Phi^*,\mathscr{H},\Phi)$ it is sufficient to specify the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and the topological vector space $\Phi\subset \mathscr{H}$. The necessary requirement is that the imbedding of $\Phi$ into $\mathscr{H}$ is continuous with respect to the topology of $\Phi$, so this gives the imbedding of $\mathscr{H}^*=\mathscr{H}\subset \Phi^*$.

Therefore, we consider the triple $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T})$, where $\mathscr{T}$ is the topology of $\Phi$, ***as defining the Gel'fand triple $(\Phi^*,\mathscr{H},\Phi)$***.

Consider the class of Gel'fand triples; we may define a morphism $f$ between objects of the class $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T})$ and $(\mathscr{K},\Psi,\mathscr{R})$ as following:

- $f(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T})$ is a triple of sets $(A,B,C)$;
- $f\rvert_{Hilb}:\mathscr{H}\to \mathscr{K}$ is a morphism of Hilbert spaces, $f\lvert_{Hilb}(\mathscr{H})=A$;
- $f\rvert_{Top}:(\Phi,\mathscr{T})\to (\Psi,\mathscr{R})$ is a morphism of topological vector spaces, $f\lvert_{Top}(\Phi,\mathscr{T})=(B,C)$;
- $(\Psi,\mathscr{R})$ is continuously imbedded in $\mathscr{K}$ (i.e. $(\mathscr{K},\Psi,\mathscr{R})$ is a triple).

The map is an isomorphism if each of the reduced maps is an isomorphism (i.e. if it is one-to-one and $A=\mathscr{K}$, $B=\Phi$, $C=\mathscr{T}$). [The inverse map $f^{-1}=(\,f\rvert_{Hilb}^{-1}\,,\,f\rvert_{Top}^{-1}\,)$]

Obviously there are non-isomorphic triples, simply choose a triple $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T}_1)$ and the triple $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T}_2)$ with $\mathscr{T}_1\subset \mathscr{T}_2$ (i.e. $\mathscr{T}_2$ a topology strictly finer than $\mathscr{T}_1$) and $(\Phi,\mathscr{T}_1)$, $(\Phi,\mathscr{T}_2)$ not homeomorphic (I suppose that e.g. different cardinality of $\mathscr{T}_1$ and $\mathscr{T}_2$ would do the trick).

Given $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and the spaces $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (rapid decrease smooth functions) and $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (compactly supported smooth functions) we have that $(\mathscr{S}',L^2,\mathscr{S})$ and $(\mathscr{D}',L^2,\mathscr{D})$ are not isomorphic w.r.t. the definition above ($\mathscr{D}$ and $\mathscr{S}$ are not homeomorphic, because $\mathscr{S}$ is metrizable while $\mathscr{D}$ is not).

Comment: your definition of isomorphism doesn't really convince me, as it seems that it lacks some "symmetry" between both sides.

Comment: @Phoenix87 clarified the definition of the morphism a little bit ;-)

Comment: "Obviously there are non-isomorphic triples, simply choose a triple $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T}_1)$ and the triple $(\mathscr{H},\Phi,\mathscr{T}_2)$ with $\mathscr{T}_1\subset \mathscr{T}_2$ (i.e. $\mathscr{T}_2$ a topology strictly finer than $\mathscr{T}_1$)." I agree that I can choose such triples (your example below), but are you sure that this is enough to ensure that the triples are non-isomorphic? If yes, can you explain to me why you are sure, such that I can also be sure?

Comment: $\mathscr{T}_2$ is strictly finer than $\mathscr{T}_1$ means that the set $\mathscr{T}_2$ contains all the elements of $\mathscr{T}_1$ and is different from $\mathscr{T}_1$. So no map (as function of sets) that associates elements of $\mathscr{T}_2$ to elements of $\mathscr{T}_1$ can be one-to-one. Therefore the two topological vector spaces cannot be [homeomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism).

Comment: @yuggib The topological space structure alone is not enough to ensure that such such topological spaces are non-homeomorphic. Best try to think of a counter example yourself. Here is one, but I don't explain it well: "Take two topological spaces with the same base space such that one topology is finer. Create a new space as countable disjoint union of these spaces. You can just "shift" in this new space to make the topology appear finer (or coarser), without really changing the topology at all.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel sorry but this example is not clear at all for me...If the set $X$ is the same, but you give two different topologies $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that $T_1$ includes strictly $T_2$, you cannot associate the couples $(x,t_1)$, $x\in X$ and $t_1\in T_1$ to each couple $(x_2,t_2)$ in a one-to-one way: once you have identified each $(x,t_2)$, $x\in X$ and $t_2\in T_2\subset T_1$ in a trivial way, you still have to identify $(x,t_1)$, $x\in X$ and $t_1\in T_1\setminus T_2\neq \emptyset$ with some $(x',t')\in (X,T_2)$, but you have already covered all of them.

Comment: @yuggib In my example, the base space is$\bigcup_{i=-\infty}^\infty X$ and the topology is $\bigcup_{i=-\infty}^0 \mathscr{T}_1 \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \mathscr{T}_2$. If you "shift", you can for example get the topology $\bigcup_{i=-\infty}^{-1} \mathscr{T}_1 \cup \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty \mathscr{T}_2$.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel I am convinced that there are strictly finer topologies with homeomorphism between the spaces (but with a simpler example than yours to be honest ;-) ). I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could support your arguments with some references :)

Comment: @Phoenix87 It would be very nice indeed...also to be sure I am not saying something wrong ;-) unluckily I don't know references on these triples, apart from the Gel'fand book on generalized eigenfunctions. I know they are still used to some extent in spectral theory to study the properties of continuous spectrum (someone in my department told me so) but I am not expert of the field.

Answer (score 3):

Item 1. has answered affirmative by Phoenix87 in the comments. Item 2. has been answered affirmative by yuggib in the other answer.

The answers to item 3. and 4. have been given without proof by Phoenix87 in the comments, namely that the $\mathbb R$- and $\mathbb R^3$-Schwartz-space are isomorphic as rigged Hilbert spaces. A nice proof of this fact is given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150549) to a simplified versions of item 3. and 4. from this question. It is the "obvious" candidate isomorphism, which maps the Hermite functions basis of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to the Hermite functions basis of $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

It seems that the question has been answered completely. But what about the motivation behind this question: "..., but is this modification also compatible the "additional hint" that all "physically relevant" Hilbert spaces are isomorphic?"
As rigged Hilbert space, $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is not really "physically relevant". My impression is that indeed many physically relevant rigged Hilbert spaces are isomorphic, i.e. the "additional hint" is not necessarily wrong.

Comment: Hi, this is especially for @yuggib. Can you take a look at my question in the math section? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130039/splitting-of-schwartz-space-of-r3-upon-hilbert-space-isomorphism